# FreqTrade not taking a position: No params for buy found, using default values

Tags: python, trading, hyperopt

My freqtrade bot wont take a position. Locally, I have no problems running or backtesting but, when running the Docker image in the cloud, it does not take a position. It has been running in the cloud for nearly 48hrs. I see indicators on my graph for jumping but, no trades. When checking the logs, I see this message:

> freqtrade    | 2022-11-08 20:36:28,178 -
> freqtrade.plugins.pairlistmanager - INFO - Whitelist with 2 pairs:
> ['DOGE/USDT', 'ETH/USDT'] freqtrade    | 2022-11-08 20:36:28,180 -
> freqtrade.strategy.hyper - INFO - No params for buy found, using
> default values. freqtrade    | 2022-11-08 20:36:28,181 -
> freqtrade.strategy.hyper - INFO - Strategy Parameter(default): buy_rsi
> = 30 freqtrade    | 2022-11-08 20:36:28,183 - freqtrade.strategy.hyper - INFO - No params for sell found, using default values. freqtrade    | 2022-11-08 20:36:28,184 - freqtrade.strategy.hyper - INFO - Strategy
> Parameter(default): sell_rsi = 70

Here is my config file:

```
{
    "max_open_trades": 1,
    "stake_currency": "USDT",
    "stake_amount": "unlimited",
    "tradable_balance_ratio": 0.99,
    "fiat_display_currency": "USD",
    "dry_run": false,
    "cancel_open_orders_on_exit": false,
    "trading_mode": "spot",
    "margin_mode": "",
    "unfilledtimeout": {
        "entry": 5,
        "exit": 5,
        "exit_timeout_count": 0,
        "unit": "minutes"
    },
    "entry_pricing": {
        "price_side": "same",
        "use_order_book": true,
        "order_book_top": 1,
        "price_last_balance": 0.0,
        "check_depth_of_market": {
            "enabled": false,
            "bids_to_ask_delta": 1
        }
    },
    "exit_pricing":{
        "price_side": "same",
        "use_order_book": true,
        "order_book_top": 1
    },
    "exchange": {
        "name": "ftx",
        "key": "nah",
        "secret": "chill",
        "ccxt_config": {
            "hostname": "ftx.us"
        },
        "ccxt_async_config": {}, 
        "pair_whitelist": [ "DOGE/USDT", "ETH/USDT"],
        "pair_blacklist": [
        ]
    },
    "pairlists": [
        {
            "method": "StaticPairList",
            "number_assets": 20,
            "sort_key": "quoteVolume",
            "min_value": 0,
            "refresh_period": 1800
        }
    ],
    "edge": {
        "enabled": false,
        "process_throttle_secs": 3600,
        "calculate_since_number_of_days": 7,
        "allowed_risk": 0.01,
        "stoploss_range_min": -0.01,
        "stoploss_range_max": -0.1,
        "stoploss_range_step": -0.01,
        "minimum_winrate": 0.60,
        "minimum_expectancy": 0.20,
        "min_trade_number": 10,
        "max_trade_duration_minute": 1440,
        "remove_pumps": false
    },
    "telegram": {
        "enabled": false,
        "token": "",
        "chat_id": ""
    },
    "api_server": {
        "enabled": true,
        "listen_ip_address": "0.0.0.0",
        "listen_port": 8080,
        "verbosity": "error",
        "enable_openapi": false,
        "jwt_secret_key": "abc123",
        "ws_token": "abc123",
        "CORS_origins": [],
        "username": "freqtrader",
        "password": "isaidchill"
    },
    "bot_name": "freqtrade",
    "initial_state": "running",
    "force_entry_enable": false,
    "internals": {
        "process_throttle_secs": 5
    }
}
```

And here is my strategy:

https://github.com/ATrueNovice/MomentumPublic/blob/main/Momentum.py

Could someone tell me why my bot is not taking a position?

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let me know if you could find out how to fix this problem.